# Column reference is ambiguous in PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created a function like this.

```
create or replace function pesquisar_imoveis_residenciais_venda()
returns table(preco decimal)
as $$
begin

    select preco from casa_venda;

end; $$

language 'plpgsql';
```

When I call it

```
  select pesquisar_imoveis_residenciais_venda()
```

I get the column reference preco is ambiguous.

I've visited some related question. But they are too difficult to follow, very complex functions.

Comment: For a simple query like that a `language sql` function would be more efficient

Answer (score 3):

The columns defined in the `RETURNS QUERY` clause are variables in the PL/pgSQL function body, so the ambiguity is between the variable `preco` and the table column of the same name.  You need to qualify the reference with either the table name or the function name to disambiguate that.

But your function definition has other issues.  I think you want:

```
create or replace function pesquisar_imoveis_residenciais_venda()
returns table(preco decimal)
as $$
begin
    return query select cv.preco from casa_venda cv;
end; $$

language 'plpgsql';

select *
from pesquisar_imoveis_residenciais_venda();
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=21c1ddd9e0630066564d78ffe7eb7a68) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `plpgsql.variable_conflict` configuration parameter:

```
create or replace function pesquisar_imoveis_residenciais_venda()
returns table(preco decimal)
as $$
#variable_conflict use_column
begin

    select preco from casa_venda;

end; $$

language 'plpgsql';
```

This assumes you want to use the column value and not the variable value.  If that's not the case then specify `#variable_conflict use_variable` instead.

See the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html) for further details.

Answer (score -2):

it means column name Preco in table casa_venda is not exist or exist more than 1 time.

Comment: This is wrong. Problem is ```preco``` is also the name of an output column and therefore ambigious.